# Can't Dynamically Bind Click Handler Using Backbone and jQuery Mobile and Sender Data

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm following a tutorial here: http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2012/01/from-list-to-details-view-using.html

I am trying to dynamically bind a click handler to a listview item as it is rendered. The method described in the link above does not work. I have tried several alternatives..

The tutorial suggests this in the render function: (template is below)

```
    activities.each(function(activity){
        var renderedItem = template(activity.toJSON()),
        $renderedItem = $(renderedItem);  //convert the html into an jQuery object
        $renderedItem.jqmData('activityId', activity.get('id'));  //set the data on it for use in the click event
        $renderedItem.bind('click', function(){
           //This part is different in tutorial, but irrelevant
           alert("Hello.");
           alert($(this).jqmData('activityId'));    //'this' represents the element being clicked
        });
        listView.append($renderedItem);
    });
```

This does not work. The buttons get created, but nothing happens when I click, and Chrome's dev tools show only two click event listeners: document, and document

I have tried these as substitutes but nothing works. No alert message, no breakpoint hit, no registered click event listeners. ...

```
$renderedItem.on('click', function(){
       alert("Hello.");
       alert($(this).jqmData('activityId'));     //'this' represents the element being clicked
   });

$renderedItem.live('click', function(){
       alert("Hello.");
       alert($(this).jqmData('activityId'));     //'this' represents the element being clicked
   });
```

I have also tried the standard Backbone way of registering events to no avail...

```
events: {
    'click .activity-list-item':'btnSelected'
},

...

btnSelected: function(){
    alert("Hello");
    //This is what I really want. Some data attached to the sender
    alert($(this).jqmData('activityId'));
}
```

This is template:

```
<li><a href="#activity-details" class="activity-list-item"identifier="<%= id %>"><%= date %> - <%= type %></a></li>
```

Thank you, ladies and gentlemen for your time.

EDIT: I have done a test and I think, for some reason, the bind is getting removed. I can do this:

```
    myCollection.at(0).bind('click', function(){
        alert("hello");
    });
    myCollection.at(0).trigger('click');
```

...and it works as it should. Is there a reason that the binds might be getting removed?

EDIT 2: This is still not solved. Unfortunately my temporary solution was exactly that. I can delete all listview items, repopulate, and refresh and still have clickability, but if I APPEND items to the list, they are not clickable. .bind, .on, .live, .delegate. None of them work. I really wish there was more documentation about this. This is a common programming problem with no common solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like jquerymobile may be intercepting & unbinding your event bindings. This is still just a guess, since I'm not setup to test JQM apps right now,  but it looks like there is a [setting](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html) to turn off jqm's default control of event bindings for links, `linkBindingEnabled`.

You can set it like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
  $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
});
```

Try that, see if it gets you anywhere... If not, back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still does not work. :( No console errors, btw.

Comment: I completely revamped my answer with a different suggestion, based on some more research of jqm.  Give it a try, let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for that! I will explore that avenue.

Comment: This works! I must add e.preventDefault(); method to every command that spawns from my click. Otherwise, clicking will cause the program to go back to the home screen. Very strange. Acceptable workaround, but insanely silly and un-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

what happens to your listView var later in your code?
To be more specific how is the listView element attached to the DOM?
If you use listView.html() when adding it to the DOM, all child elements will loose the data and events attached to them.

Comment: The listView var is a reference to $(this.el) which in this case is 'ul'. It is used for this purpose only. It is never used again.

Comment: Correction...listView is a reference to $(this.el) which, I believe, is the same as $('ul').

Answer (score 0):

It seems my problem stemmed from calling the render method multiple times. I have this:

```
    //in the render method
    $(this.el).empty();
```

It's used it to clear the listview and redraw the newly modified collection. When an item was added to the collection, I was calling the render method to clear all items and redraw them.

This was, apparently, removing event handlers from my view. This seems counter-intuitive. It works the first time, why wouldn't it work again? jQuery .empty() doc:

```
    "To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and 
    event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements 
    themselves."
```

To fix the problem, I added a detach before the empty:

```
   $(this.el).detach();
   $(this.el).empty();
```

I'm not sure if this is a good practice because of my newbness, but it works and if I'm understanding this correctly, I am detaching the the event listeners from the items before clearing them. Thus retaining the listeners for the future list items.

Essentially, calling the .empty() method on the view itself, $(this.el), seems to remove the ABILITY to add more event handlers using the method in my render function. My guess is that there is another way to add event handlers after an .empty() has been performed. I'd love it if someone could confirm or correct me on this.

Comment: Here's a good read on the subject: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

Comment: Excellent. This guy seems to know exactly what my obstacles and frustrations are.